# why does my topnavigation puts the asked page under the current page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

if i click a link (a-tag) on the top navigation bar, i get the asked
    page under the current page... Even if i put an absolute link .

i try to do the navigation in the slider on an external js-file. the slider works fine, but if the slider is used and afterwards you want a page from the top navigation bar, the link works, but in stead of giving a new screen, it places the page under the current page.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Source+Sans+Pro:700|Dosis:400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../gdigit_icon.png"/>  

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/respond.min.js'></script>
<script src="scripts/steps.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="dienstenpage" onload="design()">
<div id="wrapper"  >

        <div id="topnav" >
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="Welkom  e">WELKOM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="diensten.html"  title="de diensten  " class="currentLink">DIENSTEN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"  title=" contacteren    >CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="referenties.html" title="Algemene voorwaarden  >REFERENTIES</a></li>
                    </ul>
         </div>

    <!-- "content" -->
    <div id="content" >


            <h2>webdesign stappenplan</h2>



        <ul id = "issues">
                <li>
                    <h1>Plan</h1>
                    <p>tekst</p>
                    <p>tekst</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Design</h1>
                    <p>tekst</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Build</h1>
                    <p>tekst.</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Refine</h1>
                    <p>Atekst.</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>
                </li>  
                <li>
                    <h1>Launch</h1>
                    <p>Wtekst</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <a class="previous" href="#">prev</a>  
                </li>  
            </ul>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer not knowing what any of the random JS files you included are. Make a jsfiddle or snipplet with a running example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azLoLxt0/

Comment: it is the jquery mobile link that causes the problem. if i removeit , i can navigate, but swipe isn't working